# GMP library function

Tags: c++

Is there any function in the GMP library which give me bitLength of any GMP variable?

```
mpz_t temp;
mpz_init(temp);
mpz_set_ui(temp,356678789);
```

Then how to find bitlength of temp?

Comment: number of bits of given number. (eg 25 then binary value 11001 and bit length =5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better, way, but after reading [the docs](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling.html#Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling) I came up with this one:

```
mp_bitcnt_t msb(mpz_t& m) {
  mpz_t n = m.get_moz_t();
  mp_bitcnt_t remaining = mpz_popcount(n), last = -1;
  while (remaining) {
    --remaining;
    last = mpz_scan1(n, last + 1);
  }
  return last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GMP has a library function that does that for you:

```
size_t mpz_sizeinbase (mpz_t OP, int BASE)
```

Then `mpz_sizeinbase(temp,2);` is the number of bits required to represent `abs(temp)`:

> Return the size of OP measured in number of digits in the given BASE. BASE can vary from 2 to 62. The sign of OP is ignored, just the absolute value is used. The result will be either exact or 1 too big. If BASE is a power of 2, the result is always exact.  If OP is zero the return value is always 1.